# Wake PIC16F1825 from sleep with RS232

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, pic, wakeup

Is it possible to wake a Microchip PIC16F1825 from sleep using RS232 without looking characters?

Because one of the permissible RX pins supports interrupt on change, I thought this might be possible.

Has anybody implemented this successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

From datasheet [PIC16(L)F1825/1829](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41440C.pdf):

**9.1 Wake-up from Sleep**

```
The device can wake-up from Sleep through one of the following events:
1. External Reset input on MCLR pin, if enabled
2. BOR Reset, if enabled
3. POR Reset
4. Watchdog Timer, if enabled
5. Any external interrupt
6. Interrupts by peripherals capable of running 
   during Sleep (see individual peripheral for more information)
```

So you can use:

1)External interrupt INTERRUPT-ON-CHANGE, if you are connecting RX pin with one  of other pins which is configured as interrupt-on-change.

2)Peripheral interrupt RCIF: USART Receive Interrupt Flag bit. When receiver buffer is full (one UART word is received), an interrupt is pending and your CPU should wake up.

Comment: Have you tried either of those methods? Regarding (1): Am I understanding correctly that I can either configure the pin as IOC or as RX but cannot use the same pin for both?

Comment: @Arik Raffael Funke: you can not use RX pin as IOC but you can connect RX pin with another MCPU pin which is configured as IOC and use it for wake-up.